# Equal subsquare sums

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, constructive-mathematics

Let an $11\times 11$ square filled with numbers from 1 to 121. Is there a construction such that every $3 \times 3$ square has the same sum? Is there any generalization of the problem for $6n-1 \times 6n-1 $ squares?

My work: For the case of $5 \times 5$ square I found that we can achieve it (every $3 \times 3$ subsquare has sum 93)

Comment: For $5\times 5$, the common sum is at least $93$ and at most $141$:
\begin{pmatrix}16 &11 &23 &5 &7 \\
6 &2 &17 &15 &10 \\
19 &22 &25 &21 &18 \\ 
14 &12 &24 &3 &8 \\
4 &1 &20 &13 &9\end{pmatrix}